# SSE Implementation (Weblogic 12.2.1.2.0 + Jax-RS 2.1 (used to register resource) + CXF 3.2.5+ + Springboot + jersey 2.25.1)

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, weblogic12c, server-sent-events

Trying to implement SSE with mentioned technologies but failing in deployment of micro service -

```
Resource - 
    @Path("/status-management")
    public interface ISocketResource  {
        @GET
        @Path("/v1/statusSocket")
        @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
        public void stockEvents(
            @QueryParam("entityProcessContexts") List<String> entityProcessContexts, 
            @Context Sse sse, 
            @Context SseEventSink sseEventSink);
    }
```

CXF server registration -

```
@Bean
public Server cxfServer() {
    List<Object> serviceBeans = new ArrayList<Object>(ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class).values());

    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>(ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(Provider.class).values());
    providers.add(new FormEncodingProvider<Object>());      
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    factory.setBus(ctx.getBean(SpringBus.class));
    factory.setServiceBeans(serviceBeans);
    factory.setProviders(providers);    
    factory.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(new SseFeature()));// registering SseFeature
    Server server = factory.create();
    return server;
}
```

Exception - failing when jersey is trying to load ext @Provider class - OutboundSseEventBodyWriter of CXF package.

OutboundSseEventBodyWriter class has a protected constructor that is not causing problem.

```
    WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.sse.OutboundSseEventBodyWriter] with an exception:
    MultiException stack 1 of 2
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.sse.OutboundSseEventBodyWriter class.
            at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:192)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:180)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:129)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:180)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:740)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:694)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1395)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1390)
            at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1452)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1377)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1366)
....
.
.
.
.
.
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
        implementation=org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.sse.OutboundSseEventBodyWriter
        contracts={javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter}
        scope=javax.inject.Singleton
        qualifiers={org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Custom}
        descriptorType=CLASS
        descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
        metadata=
        rank=0
        loader=null
        proxiable=null
        proxyForSameScope=null
        analysisName=null
        id=189
        locatorId=0
        identityHashCode=1355595726
        reified=false)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:705)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1395)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1390)
.
.
.
.

<Nov 20, 2018, 11:19:17,989 AM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "JAX-RS/Jersey#1" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/businessstatus-ms".
A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.InstantiationException
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractResponseViewProvider

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:392)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.InstantiationException
        at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: _"OutboundSseEventBodyWriter class has a protected constructor that is not causing problem."_ - I believe it needs to be public for HK2 to create it. I may be wrong. Can you confirm @jwells131313? ([for reference](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/cxf-3.2.5/rt/rs/sse/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/sse/OutboundSseEventBodyWriter.java))

Answer (score 0):

Check out suggestions on how to use Apache CXF on WebLogic here:
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-deployment.html
Look at the WebLogic section.